# Storing c++ structs/objects in NSData

Tags: c++, objective-c, opencv, nsdata, mat

I am developing an iOS with OpenCV. 
OpenCV is an Open Source Image Library and works with C++.

I want to store some data from the Library in an NSData object. 
Is it possible to convert a c++ struct to NSData without losing the object?

```
- (void)addMat:(cv::Mat)mat andImageName:(NSString *)name {


self.myMat = [NSData dataWithBytes:&mat length:sizeof(mat)];
self.imageName = name;
```

}

Now I'm using the code above. 
But this NSData only stores the pointers not the actual data. 
When I try to get the object back I

> pointer being freed was not allocated
>   *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug

My data should be stored in a SqLite Database.

Do you have an idea to convert everything ?

I tried to convert every single property. This worked for some properties quite well and for others it didn't work.

I hope you could help me.

Thank you.

Greetings,

Alexander Heinrich

Comment: looks good, how are you trying to get the struct back?

Comment: cv::Mat mat;
    [self.myMat getBytes:&mat length:sizeof(mat)];
    
    return mat;

As Cy-4Ah said the pointers get lost.

Answer (score 1):

You may write bytes from objects inside data, but it doesn't store object. For example object can have pointers at other objects and they can become invalid after some time, but yours NSData copy will not know about that.

You should turn on Objective-C++ and work direct with C++ structures/classes.

Comment: I'm working in Objective C ++ 
Is it possible to store the C++ structure in other ways ? 
Without loosing the pointers

Comment: @Sn0wfreeze, why and where you need store objects? Why you can't just use types from OpenCV?